# how to update table from other table by using from and its id

Tags: sql-update

I want to update my play_log_new table country value by its ip using an ip_range table.
Here is my query in mysql:

```
update play_log_new pln
set country = ipr.country_name
from ip_range ipr where (INET_ATON(pln.ip) BETWEEN ipr.ip_start_digit AND ipr.ip_end_digit)
and pln.ip is not null  and pln.country is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below sql, better if you can provide 2 table details

```
UPDATE
    `play_log_new` AS `pln`,
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            `ip_range`
        WHERE
            INET_ATON(`pln`.`ip`) BETWEEN `ip_range`.`ip_start_digit` AND `ip_range`.`ip_end_digit`
    ) AS `ipr`
SET
    `pln`.`country` = `ipr`.`country_name`
WHERE
    `pln`.`ip` is not null  and `pln`.`country` is null
```

Comment: the ip_range table is just a bulk of ips it does not have the same ip in order to use join. I just want to find my ip rane from ip_range table then use the country value.

Comment: Updated answer as per your table structure